# Choose mode for saving a Dask array to hdf5 file

Tags: python, dask

Can I choose file mode when I save a dask array to a hdf5 file?

The `to_hdf5` method doesn't have a `mode` keyword.

Test:

```
import dask.array as da
a = da.arange(12, chunks=3)
a.to_hdf5('a.hdf5', '/a', mode='a')
```

Result:

```
...
TypeError: make_new_dset() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html#dask.array.to_hdf5), `to_hdf()` uses `h5py.File.create_dataset`, and arguments are passed to it - i.e., it will append to an existing file/dataset by default. Alternatively, if you want more control over how to write your data, the example under `.store()` may be illuminating:

```
>>> import h5py  
>>> f = h5py.File('myfile.hdf5')  
>>> dset = f.create_dataset('/data', shape=x.shape,
...                                  chunks=x.chunks,
...                                  dtype='f8')  
>>> store(x, dset)
```

This does essentially the same thing, but you could create your file and dataset in any way convenient to you - `store()` merely requires something with a numpy array-like interface.